# HTML in PHP which contains PHP

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to put PHP-code surrounded by HTML which is surrounded by PHP?
Here is a little code-snippet. All of that is in PHP-brackets. The browser displays the table but not the PHP values.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $Auftragsnummer;?></td>';
echo '<td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $Modellbezeichnung;?></td>';
echo '<td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $Untersuchungsart;?></td>';
echo '<td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $TUEV_Stelle;?></td>';
echo '<td class="tg-031e"><?php echo $TUEV_Termin;?></td>';
echo "</tr>";
```

Regards
Bluefox

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: I would use `sprintf()` instead of co-mingling the HTML and php. It does more-or-less the same thing and is easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concatenation

```
echo '<td class="tg-031e">' . $Auftragsnummer . '</td>';
```

But if you have a lot of HTML it's better to close your php tag

```
<?php your code ?>
  <tr>
   <td class="yourClass"> <?php echo $yourVar; ?> </td>
  <tr>
```

Comment: My HTML is rather small. Your first solution worked great! I just needed to add a '.' after the variable.

Answer (score 1):

[Look at **Concatenation**.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

You can put a string in an `echo` command like so:

```
$string = 'hello world';
echo 'I wanted to say '.$string.'!'; //outputs "I wanted to say hello world!"
```

so your code should look like:

```
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="tg-031e">'.$Auftragsnummer.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="tg-031e">'.$Modellbezeichnung.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="tg-031e">'.$Untersuchungsart.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="tg-031e">'.$TUEV_Stelle.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="tg-031e">'.$TUEV_Termin'.</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Of course I added it, it clarifies what I'm explaining, it's making the answer better, and will hopefully help the OP understand the reasoning behind using a string in an `echo` command. I know he's aware of `echo`, I'm saying that there is a way to put a string in an `echo` command. What's with the hostility?

Comment: LOL what hostility? "clarifies what I'm explaining" - You aren't explaining anything in your answer so I don't understand what you mean. "OP understand the reasoning"  - what reasoning?

Comment: "I like how you added concatenation after you noticed the other guy got some upvotes" "why are you even mentioning echo" - sorry if I misread that, but it felt a bit aggressive mate

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to close the php bracket
do more like this

```
 echo '<td class="tg-031e">' .$Auftragsnummer. '</td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for HEREDOC :

```
$html = <<<HTML
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-031e">{$Auftragsnummer}</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">{$Modellbezeichnung}</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">{$Untersuchungsart}</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">{$TUEV_Stelle}</td>
                <td class="tg-031e">{$TUEV_Termin}</td>
            </tr>
HTML
;

echo $html;
```

Comment: I wish more people used HEREDOC.  Much cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

echo is PHP. So you should just do something like this :

```
echo '<td class="tg-031e">'.$Auftragsnummer.'</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sprintf()`.

```
<?php
echo sprintf('<td class="tg-031e">%s</td>', $Auftragsnummer);
```

Or, as a loop/array construct:

```
foreach(array(
   $Auftragsnummer, 
   $Modellbezeichnung, 
   $Untersuchungsart, 
   $TUEV_Stelle, 
   $TUEV_Termin) as $item) {
    echo sprintf('<td class="tg-031e">%s</td>', $item);
}
```